# What is the new primary key when we apply natural join on two tables?

Tags: database, relational-database, natural-join

If there are two tables:

`table1` with attributes `a1, a2, a3` and `table2` with attributes `b1, b2, b3`. And `a1` and `b1` being their respective primary keys. What's the new primary key when the natural join is applied on the two tables. Do  `a1, b1` combine to form a **composite primary key** or they become **two separate candidate keys**

Comment: What makes you think that he DBMS creates a new primary key (of any kind) when it creates a dataset (i.e. the result of a select)? When you run a select, the result is a **list of 0 or more records**, not a new **table**.

Comment: I cannot grasp the premise of the question. There is no 'new' PK

Comment: So what can be considered as the primary key in the new joined table?

Comment: There is no "joined table", there is just the join.

Comment: An essential feature of the relational model of data is that query results, views and base tables all have the same data structure. The common data structure is called a Relation. A relation always has a key (or keys) and therefore the concept of keys is relevant in query results just as it is in base tables.

Comment: From the presence of FDs (functional dependencies) in the operand tables we can also mechanically [derive/infer](https://books.google.ca/books?id=npdn5wROkecC&pg=PA215) that certain CKs (candidate keys) (& FDs) are in the result beyond the ones @sqlvogel's answer describes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In relational database terms the result should have keys corresponding to every key from one relation paired with every key from the other (i.e. the "natural-join" of the candidate keys, not just one key per relation). So if A1 and B1 are the only keys in your example then the only key in the natural-joined result would be (A1,B1).

However, you tagged your question with MySQL. MySQL is a SQL DBMS, not relational. MySQL doesn't support the relational model concept of key derivation. In MySQL there is no physical implementation of any key in the result of such a query.